# How to set test options when running weka using python-weka-wrapper?

Tags: python, python-3.x, weka

I'm exploring python's weka wrapper with JRip classifier. I loaded the dataset, buildt a model and extracted the rules without any major problem.

Now, as far as I know, cross-validation with 10 folds is the default option when using Weka Explorer, as shown in the image below.

[image: Weka Explorer]

So I assume that if I run the same JRip classifier but written in python, the default mode would be a 10 fold Cross-Validation, but I'm not sure. My code is as follows:

```
import weka.core.jvm as jvm

from weka.core.converters import Loader
from weka.classifiers import Classifier,Evaluation
from random import randint

jvm.start()
url = 'C:/Data/train_dataset.csv'
loader = Loader(classname = 'weka.core.converters.CSVLoader')
data = loader.load_file(url)
data.class_is_last()
seed = randint(1,99e6)
optimizations = 15 
options = f'-F 3 -N 2.0 -O {optimizations} -S {seed}'.split()
jrip = Classifier(classname = 'weka.classifiers.rules.JRip',options=options)
jrip.build_classifier(data)
ruleset = jrip.jwrapper.getRuleset()
for i in range(ruleset.size()):
    rule = ruleset.get(i)
    print(rule.toString(data.class_attribute.jobject))
```

The code is pretty standard, extracted from mostly examples from weka's website (never used Weka in Python before).

I also read about Evaluation class that has a crossvalidate_model method, but I'm not sure if this is what I'm looking for and how to correctly use it.

How can I build a model and apply different settings, or know which settings I'm actually using, in the python script? For example, if I want to increase the number of folds or use other settings like `Percentage split`, `Supplied test` set or `Use training set`?

Answer (score 1):

## Evaluation

In your code example you trained a classifier (JRip) on the full dataset, you didn't perform cross-validation or any other form of evaluation. The `weka.classifiers.Evaluation` Python class is used for evaluating models.

The [example repository](https://github.com/fracpete/python-weka-wrapper3-examples) contains examples for:

- [cross-validation](https://github.com/fracpete/python-weka-wrapper3-examples/blob/master/src/wekaexamples/classifiers/classifiers.py) (doc: [Evaluation.crossvalidate_model](http://fracpete.github.io/python-weka-wrapper3/weka.html#weka.classifiers.Evaluation.crossvalidate_model))
- [train/test splits](https://github.com/fracpete/python-weka-wrapper3-examples/blob/master/src/wekaexamples/classifiers/train_test_split.py)
  (doc: [Evaluation.test_model](http://fracpete.github.io/python-weka-wrapper3/weka.html#weka.classifiers.Evaluation.test_model), convenience method: [Evaluation.evaluate_train_test_split](http://fracpete.github.io/python-weka-wrapper3/weka.html#weka.classifiers.Evaluation.evaluate_train_test_split))

Only the `test_model` requires a trained classifier (as you evaluate its predictions against a test set). The `crossvalidate_model` and `evaluate_train_test_split` methods should only receive a configured classifier object, not a trained classifier.

## Option handling

If you want to know what options a classifier has set, simply retrieve the list of options via the `options` property. If you want to change them, then set them by providing a list to that same property.

```py
c = Classifier(...)
# print current options
print(c.options)
# set new options
c.options = ['-SOME', 'NEW', 'OPTIONS']
```

Alternatively, you can call the classiifer's `to_commandline()` method to get the same command-line string that Weka provides when copying it in the Weka Explorer (most classes like filters, classifiers and clusters in Weka are *option handlers*, i.e., they have this method).

Since Weka's option handling is a bit different (nesting is done via double quotes and inner nesting via backslash-escaped quotes), you should use the method `split_options` from the `weka.core.classes` module to split a command-line string (with or without classname) into a list of values.

Or, instead of manually splitting the commandline string, you can use the `from_commandline()` method of the `weka.core.classes` module which allows you to split a single string consisting of classname and option into a Weka object. E.g.,:

```py
from weka.core.classes import from_commandline
cmdline = 'weka.classifiers.functions.SMO -K "weka.classifiers.functions.supportVector.NormalizedPolyKernel -E 3.0"'
classifier = from_commandline(cmdline, classname="weka.classifiers.Classifier")
```